# How to create multiple view of same type programmatically with different resource id

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I want to create multiple views of same type.I have created one view.

```
LinearLayout mainRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
```

This is the parent layout.I want to create multiple view under main root.I can use add method to add custom view.But how am i supposed to work out with resource id.

I don't know how to access individual items, as they all have the same id.

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply use listview.

Comment: You can create all view programmatically and add them in parent layout. And for id you can use 'view.setId(int)' method

Comment: @SarithaG thanks but without listview  or recycler view is there any way to do that

Comment: you can inflater the view and add text or something dynamically in a loop.

Comment: What is your exact requirement

Comment: @NarendraKothamire i want to append a view of same type..like user click two view then 2 views will generate same type.

Answer (score 1):

You can set some tag to those views that you create by using the [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)) method.

And then when you want to access those views you could use [findViewWithTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)) to get the view that you are looking for.

UPDATE:

```
        LinearLayout mainRoot = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
        for (int i = 0; i < numCustomViews; i++) {
            View customView = new View(this);
            customView.setTag(i);
            mainRoot.addView(customView);
        }

        // Find view with tag 4
        View view5 = mainRoot.findViewWithTag(4);
        Log.d("XXX", view5.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks let me try like that

Comment: One more thing like if i create 10 views how may i set tag for 10 views at a time

Comment: I'd suggest settings tags like numbers. If you have those 10 views in a loop, set the tags to be loop counter like 1,2,3....10. And then fetch the views by those numbers again.

Comment: Okay But how to fetch by those numbers,Can you please more clear

Comment: Okay ,But if i want to create it without loop

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to set the id for each View By using **setId**

```
Button btn=new Button(this);
btn.setId(1);
Button btn1=new Button(this);
btn.setId(2);
your_linear_Layout.add(btn);
your_linear_Layout.add(btn1);
```

now in your onClick method

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){

     case 1:

        //btn clicked
       break;
     case 2:

       // btn1 clicked.
       break;

  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RecyclerView instead of custom View.
1. you can add and remove from RecyclerView.
2. you will get the ClickEvent.
3. Recycler View can be Vertically or horizontally on your requirement.

Go through this [Sample of RecyclerView](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/07/add-and-remove-items-to-recyclerview.html)

Comment: Can i add multiple view of same type using Recycler view.